# How can we create our own Custom HTML report for Cucumber based Selenium Project?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, testcase, test-report

I have a Cucumber based Selenium framework written in Java. Now, for reporting i use some common plugins/libraries like Extent report. That is fine.

However, i want to create my own **custom** HTML report, where each test step inside a Cucumber scenario is logged with say Apache Log4j and corresponding screenshot is linked to the step.

Is there any dependency/lib that can be used to  create own .html format reports after the test run completes?

Something like this....

```
Scenario 1
Test step  1        -------------- Screenshot link
Test step  2         ---------------screenshot link

Scenario 2
Test step  1        -------------- Screenshot link
Test step  2         ---------------screenshot link
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom **HTML** file using the **FileWriter** class of **Java**.

I used the same to create a custom HTML test report for one of my projects.

In that projects, everything that I wanted in the report, I added it to an array with each step execution.

At the end of the test, I wrote all the data gathered within the array into the HTML file using FileWriter.

Here is a sample code:

```
File resultFile;
Writer fileWriter;
resultFile = new File(Results.html");
// if file doesn't exists, then create it...
if (!resultFile.exists()) {
    resultFile.createNewFile();
}

fileWriter = new FileWriter(resultFile.getAbsoluteFile());

fileWriter.write("<html><title>Test result</title><body>");
fileWriter.write("Your text OR your Log4j entries OR <span>HTML with custom result</span> goes here...");
fileWriter.write("Can do more than one writes to single file.");
fileWriter.write("It appends data to file.");
fileWriter.write("</body></html>");
fileWriter.close();
```

and few reference links for the FileWriter class:

https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_files_create.asp

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/filewriter-class-in-java/

https://www.javatpoint.com/java-filewriter-class